# Why my firebase project does not recognize new version?

Tags: firebase, google-play

Sorry. I'm not good at english.

When I update my app to 1.1.0, firebase does not recognize new version.
In firebase, my app version is still 1.0.12 and does not receive any event.

iOS is working good. but only Google has a problem.

In Play Store, People can download 1.1.0 version.

What can I do?

Comment: Clean you build folder and try again. Your Cocoapods and podfile may be out of date as well - check the versions and include them in the question. Please take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

in terminal do : `flutter clean`